# Define nested data type using enum

Tags: java, enums

I want to define nested constants using `enum` in java

```
public class AppConstants {    
    enum E1{        
        public enum E11{ // Here i am getting:- as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
            var1
        }       
        public enum E12{
            var1
        }        
    }
}
```

My aim is to access like `E1.E11.var1` or define a type 'E1.E11`. What is the solution or alternatives ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
enum E1 {
    ; // <--
    enum E11 {}
    ...
```

If an enum has declarations besides constants, the (in this case, empty) constants section needs to be terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: I was almost close to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
enum E1{        
    E11(Object var1_value1), E12(Object var1_value2);
    Object var1;
    E1(Object var){
      var1=var;
     }
}
```

You can use E1.E12.var1 after that